# WSO2 IOTS: Update device plugin code to server

Tags: wso2

Sorry for my bad English.
I follow [document in here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS100/Creating+a+New+Device+Type) and success deploy new device type in to my server iots.
My question:
 `How deploy again when I modified some code.`

Currently, I must delete wo2server directory and extract again and deploy again each time when update source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able uninstall your device type plugin feature using wso2 carbon console as mentioned in the [carbon documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/Uninstalling+Features). Then deploy your plugin again as you did previously.

You can access WSO2 carbon console for IoT server as follows:https://localhost:9443/carbon

Use 'admin' as user name and password to log in.

Thanks.